# how to submit the form if textarea is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a form which contain three textarea.I want to submit my form if one of the textarea is clicked.

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <div class="time">
    <div class="time-control">
      <div class="tcont-in">
        <p>Morning</p>
        <textarea name="time" id="foo" style="color: white; background-color: black; height:30px;position: absolute;left:608px" readonly>05PM-12PM</textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="time-control">
      <div class="tcont-in">
        <p>Afternoon</p>
        <textarea name="time2" id="foo1" style="color: white; background-color: black; height:30px; position: absolute;left:608px" readonly>12PM-05PM</textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="time-control">
      <div class="tcont-in">
        <p>Evening</p>
        <textarea name="time3" id="foo2" style="color: white; background-color: black; height:30px; position: absolute;left:608px" readonly>05PM-10PM</textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="check-control">
    <div class="pref-checkbox">
      <div class="checkbox-time">
        <input type="checkbox" value="No" id="checkboxFourInput" name="Preference" checked="" />
        <label for="checkboxFourInput"></label>
      </div>
      <h3>No Preference</h3> 
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="">
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn-next">NEXT</button>
  </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Why don't you just make them submit buttons? Style them to look however you want.

Comment: Seems like you're trying to troll the user. xD

Comment: It might help if you include why you want to do this. It isn't necessary for that in order to answer your question but it seems like a counter intuitive user interface to submit when the user clicks in a text area. The user would be expecting to be able to edit the text area.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't think of any reason for this to be actually usable. You simply do not want to submit anything when clicking on a text area. Or is your question just misspelled? Do you actually want to enable the submit button when there is content in one of the text areas?

Comment: sorry,now i realised how fool i was.Thanks to every one for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind using JQuery, you can use something like this:

```
$('textarea[id^="foo"]').on(
    'click',
    function()
    {
        $('button[type="submit"]').trigger('click');
    }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the `submit()` function available you can attach a `click` listener to the textarea and run the `submit()` function.

```
document.getElementById("myTextAreaId").addEventListener("click", function () {
    document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

simple add onclick or onblur event to all textboxes

like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.textboxClass').on('change click blur keyup', submitForm);           
    });

function submitForm(){
    $('#form').submit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<form>
   <textarea class="messagearea">Write your message here...</textarea>
</form>
```

Put this in JS:

```
$('.messagearea').keydown(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        $(this.form).submit()
        return false;
     }
}).focus(function(){
    if(this.value == "Write your message here..."){
         this.value = "";
    }

}).blur(function(){
    if(this.value==""){
         this.value = "Write your message here...";
    }
});
```